# Is there an R function to find local mins and maxes?

Tags: r, function, vector, max, min

Is there a function in R that can take a vector as input and output a vector with local mins and maxes, and where they occur in the original vector?

Comment: Can you show a small  example and expected output

Comment: If you just want to look at first differences, something like `min_max = which(diff(sign(diff(x))) != 0) + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Let `v` be a plain vector and define a peak as an element which is strictly larger than the elements to either side and similarly for trough.

**1) rollapply** Then the following gives two logical vectors each having the same length as v.  One indicates positions of peaks using TRUE and FALSE for other positions and the other indicates troughs in the same manner.  `which(peaks)` and `which(troughs)` can be used to get the index numbers if that representation is preferred.

```
library(zoo)

peaks <- rollapply(v, 3, function(x) x[2] > max(x[-2]), fill = FALSE)
troughs <- rollapply(v, 3, function(x) x[2] < min(x[-2]), fill = FALSE)
```

We could combine them like this where each output component is 1 if it is a peak, -1 if it is a trough and 0 otherwise.

```
extreme <- function(x) (x[2] > max(x[-2])) - (x[2] < min(x[-2]))
rollapply(v, 3, extreme, fill = FALSE)
```

**2) Base R** A base R method would be:

```
prev <- c(NA, v[-length(v)])
post <-  c(v[-1], NA)
(v > pmax(prev, post)) - (v < pmin(prev, post))
```